# Kerberized ssh - key exchange is slow

Tags: ssh, kerberos

After several days of hammering at this, I have a working CentOS 6.3 system bound to a AD domain running Windows 2008R2.  My method is sssd based pam using Kerberos authentication.  Directory info is accessed on the domain controller via LDAP.  The LDAP bind is also kerberized.

On my client (Mac OS 10.8) I am able to ssh into the CentOS system with all the pieces seemingly clicking right.  The Mac gets a ticket and then GSSAPI key exchange takes place followed by gssapi-keyex authentication.  So the setup is working but I'm having an issue with slow logins -- about 10 seconds from start to finish.  My experience is that kerberized ssh should be instantaneous so something is still not right.

I've monitored the communication between CentOS and the DC using tcpdump and it looks like CentOS gets a response immediately from anything it requests from the DC. The part that it hangs up is actually before it tries to contact the DC at all.  It looks like the GSSAPI key exchange is what is slow.  So if I look at the ssh connection in debug mode the two points it hangs are

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

and

```
debug1: Doing group exchange
```

Once it gets to authentication method: gssapi-keyex it flys through.  Does anybody have any ideas as to what would cause the key exchange to run slow?  Possibly is something not right on my client?  On the Mac my ~/.ssh/config file is set as follows:

```
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIKeyExchange yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
GSSAPITrustDNS yes
GSSAPIClientIdentity username@MYDOMAIN.COM
```

Comment: Please move to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, Kerberos makes many many DNS calls and you must have a caching DNS server installed to CentOS if you want to have practical login speeds.  So simply install and set up BIND and you'll be good to go.